# Como puedo comparar dos posiciones en onLocationChanged?

Tags: android, gps

Quiero al obtener las coordenadas del metodo `onLocationChanged` pueda comparar si la distancia a la anterior es mayor a 2 metros, y así no registrarla en base de datos .

Comment: Jhonatan que bien agregas otra pregunta, te recomiendo agregues el código de lo que has realizado. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Es muy fácil de hacer y no tienes que calcular nada, la clase Location de Android incluye un método que te ayuda a calcular la distancia entre dos puntos.
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

El proceso sería tal que así:

/** Location A **/

Location locationA = new Location("point A");

locationA.setLatitude(latA);

locationA.setLongitude(lngA);

/** Location B **/

Location locationB = new Location("point B");

locationB.setLatitude(latB);

locationB.setLongitude(lngB);

/** Distancia entre los dos objetos Location **/

float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

Saludos

(En ingles https://stackoverflow.com/a/8050255/2878240)

Answer (score 0):

La forma de solucionarlo es con esta función

```
private double getDistance(double fromLat , double fromLong, double toLat, double toLong) {
    double d2r = Math.PI / 180;
    double dLong = (toLong - fromLong) * d2r;
    double dLat = (toLat - fromLat) * d2r;
    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(fromLat * d2r)
            * Math.cos(toLat * d2r) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dLong / 2.0), 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = 6367000 * c;
    return Math.round(d);
}
```

Recibe 4 Parámetros latitud y longitud de la primera posición y latitud y longitud de la segunda posición.

El método retorna  la distancia en metros entre los puntos.